# $\phi(a_1),\phi(a_2),\ldots$ forms an increasing arithmetic sequence?

Tags: number-theory

> Let $\phi(m)$ denote the totient of $m$. Does there exist an infinite sequence of positive integers $a_1,a_2,\ldots$ such that $\phi(a_1),\phi(a_2),\ldots$ forms an increasing arithmetic sequence?

I was wondering about this question from looking at a graph of $y=\phi(x)$:

[image]

It looks like as you go farther to the right on the $x$-axis a lot of the $\phi(x)$ become closer together making we question the existence of a line that passes through infinitely many points on the graph. Although since the sequence doesn't have to be increasing it may be something else.

Comment: By the theorem of Green and Tao, using primes we can get finite arithmetic sequences of arbitrary length. Infinite is another matter.

Comment: @AndréNicolas What do arithmetic progressions of primes have to do with $\phi(x)$? Are you suggesting that $\phi(x) =p$ where $p$ is a prime always has a solution?

Comment: I kind of recall a result that says that if $d$ is any positive integer, then there is a $k$ such that $kd$ is not $\varphi$ of anything, That would take care of the special arithmetic sequences $nd$.

Comment: If we take a (finite) arithmetic sequence of primes $p$, then the $\varphi(p)$ are a finite arithmetic sequence of values of $\varphi$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ah, I see. The problem is the infinite part.

Comment: Em. Whats wrong with this. Consider $\{a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,\} = \{2,3,5,7,\ldots\}$ basically the primes, then isn't $\phi(a_{n})$ increasing?

Comment: @S.C. Recall it must also be arithmetic.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Do you think it is possible to solve this question without having to show the theorem of Green and Tao holds for infinite sequences as well?

Comment: @Puzzled417 Oh what does it mean? Like $\phi(a_{1}), \phi(a_{2})$ should form an A.P??

Comment: @S.C. Yep, an increasing A.P.

Comment: @Puzzled417: There are no infinite arithmetic sequences of primes, so that will not work.

Comment: @Puzzled417 The existence of a line passing through infinitely many points is much weaker than the existence of an arithmetic progression.  The line $y=x-1$ already passes through infinitely many points, as does the line $y=\frac x2 -1$; and infinitely many others.

Comment: BTW the lines that the points are grouping on are all (or at least I think all) of the form $y=\alpha x$ where $\alpha=\prod_{p\in S}(1-1/p)$ for some set $S$ of primes.

Comment: @arctictem Not quite: in order for $x$ to satisfy $\phi(x) = \alpha x$, $x$ would roughly (ignoring coincidences of cancellation) need to be of the form $P \cdot w$ where $P = \prod_{p\in S} p$ and the only primes dividing $w$ are in $S$.  For a fixed $S$, this set is only poly-logarithmically dense.  On the other hand $P \cdot q$ for prime $q$ fits the line $y = \alpha(x-P)$, and is significantly more dense.  But maybe some other lines could beat it?

Comment: @Puzzled417 Note that $\phi(a_1), \phi(a_2), \ldots$ forming an arithmetic progression does *not* imply that the corresponding points fall on any line.  Are you also assuming that $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ is an arithmetic progression?

Comment: @Puzzled417 Huh??  The question is much more subtle without that assumption!  With the extra assumption that $a_1,\ldots$ must itself be an AP, it's much more elementary to show that it's impossible (though I wouldn't say trivial).  It's very easy to find three values of $a_n$ that are not collinear: why didn't you clarify that in the first place?

Answer (score 6):

No, this is impossible.  By a 1929 result of Pillai, the set of values taken by $\phi(n)$ has upper density $0$ in the integers: specifically the number of distinct values of $\phi$ up to $x$ is $\ll x (\log x)^{-(\log 2)/e} = o(x)$.  For a reference, see this landmark [paper of Kevin Ford](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.3264) which determines the correct order of magnitude for this counting function.

Thus there cannot be an infinite arithmetic progression of values of $\phi(n)$.